# Apache Camel File End point: Camel test invokes direct component route to copy files from folderA to folderB

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to apache camel and writing the camel test to validate the route. My use case is,

1. From camel test invoke route which copies files from folderA to folderB.
2. Camel route is invoked using direct component from test route.

This doesn't work for me,

```
from("direct:waitingForVideoFiles").routeId("waitingForVideoFiles")
                .to("file:E://folderA?noop=true")
                .to("file:D://folderB?FileName=ready-${file:name}")
```

My camel test direct component looks like this,

```
template.sendBody("direct:waitingForVideoFiles",null);
```

Here i can see CamelFileName is set to null.

This code works for me.

```
from("file:E://folderA?noop=true&include=.*.mov|.*.ts").routeId("VideoFilesAvailable")
                .setHeader("statusVideoFile", simple("failed"))
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "header is ${headers}")
                .to("file:D://folderB")
```

files are getting copied without direct component.

Comment: You can use controlbus to start/stop routes from routes.

Answer (score 0):

- you are passing body as null, try with some content
- If you haven't mentioned the fileName, camel will create its own file with the content you are passing.

I tried your example and that works for me

```
 @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        template.sendBody("direct:waitingForVideoFiles", "some content");
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:waitingForVideoFiles")
                        .routeId("waitingForVideoFiles")
                        .to("file:///Users/sucheth.shivakumar/Desktop/folderA");
            }
        };
    }
```

Just in case if you want to send your own file name, You can use something like this

```
template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:waitingForVideoFiles", "some body content", Exchange.FILE_NAME, "such.txt");
```

Comment: Just now observed, when we send body "some body content", it modifies the file content with "some body content". So this solution do not help me. :(

Comment: Any other help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need a PollEnrich:

```
from("direct:waitingForVideoFiles").routeId("waitingForVideoFiles")
.loopDoWhile(body().isNotNull())
  .pollEnrich("file:E://folderA?noop=true")
  .toD("file:D://folderB?FileName=ready-${file:name}")
.end();
```

Note that I've changed "to" to "toD" because of "${file:name}".

Hope it helps.

R.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This code works. In my folderA, i have 5 files, but with this code only first file is getting copied. Is there any way, i can copy all 5 files.

Comment: Just updated the answer to use loopDoWhile() @Harshal